# Не получается соединить два DataFrame по одному ключу - данные не подтягиваются

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Необходимо в датафрейм "massiv_LT" добавить данные по продажам (количество, выручка, avg) из DataFrame "LT". Ключ "sku". Подскажите пожалуйста где может быть ошибка ? Спасибо.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aBXjVtE5uFmQlV9cILSgSz5hS6WySpSU?usp=sharing

Comment: а вы уверены, что `sku` у вас одинаковый в обеих таблицах?)

Comment: Вот, что-то об этом я не подумал.. Хотя sku = номенклатура +"_" +код. Для двух датафреймов. Спасибо, я проверю.